# How to start a thread in python after waiting for a specific delay

Tags: python, multithreading, python-2.7

i have functions detection(),timeralg()

while running the timeralg() function, i want detection() to start in parallel after a specific delay.
currently i tried like this

```
def timeralg(c1,c2,c3,c4):
    t=[4,4,4,6,6,20,24,28,32,36,40]#delay determining array
    for y in range(0,3):
        print 'y is ',y
        if((c1>=c2)and(c1>=c3)):
            print 'timer1 on for'
            x=t[c1]        
            print x
            c1=0

        GPIO.output(5,False)#Red1
        GPIO.output(13,True)#red2
        GPIO.output(12,True)#red3
        GPIO.output(7,True)#green1
        if(y==2):
            t = threading.Thread(detection())
            t.start()
            print 'processing strtd in from 1'

        time.sleep(x-3)
        GPIO.output(7,False)
        GPIO.output(3,True)#Yellow1
        time.sleep(3)
        GPIO.output(3,False)#Yellow1
        GPIO.output(5,True)#Red1
```

Unlike this i want 't' to start after a specific delay specified by me.

Comment: Something went wrong with your code formatting. Consult [Markdown help - Code and Preformatted Text](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help#code) and [edit] your post.

Answer (score 5):

You could wrap `detection()` as follows:

```
def delayed_detection():
    time.sleep(3)
    detection()
```

Then start your thread with:

```
t = threading.Thread(delayed_detection)
t.start()
```

You're not delaying the spawning of the thread, but you are still achieving calling `detecton()` after three seconds

Answer (score 4):

using `sleep()` will work, but it's inefficient.  It's much better to use a [Timer](https://docs.python.org/3/library/threading.html#timer-objects) that can efficiently wait out the delay before starting the thread.

```
timer = threading.Timer(delay, detection)
timer.start().   # will execute detection() after "delay" seconds
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't wait to start the thread, have the thread wait to start working.

First create a new thread.

The new thread should do the following:

```
time.sleep(N)

while True:
  detection()
```