# Elasticsearch dsl adding foreign key

Tags: django, elasticsearch, django-models

I have a model called `Poll`, this model has a one to many relationship with another model called `Choice` 1 poll can have many choices. Every time a poll is saved, I'd like to save that poll in Elasticsearch.

**Model**:

```
class Poll(models.Model):
    user            = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    question        = models.CharField(max_length=200)

    def indexing(self):
        obj = QuestionIndex(
            meta={'id': self.id},
            question=self.question,
            choices=self.choice_set.count(), # How many choices are there?
        )
        obj.save()
        return obj.to_dict(include_meta=True)
```

**Index**

```
class QuestionIndex(Document):
    question        = Text()
    choices         = Integer()

    class Index:
        name = 'questions'
```

I have already added a signal in Django to execute to save the data in Elasticsearch. This works fine, however, I see that the value of choices is always 0 even though I add choices. The choices do get saved in my database, but the count of choices is always 0. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When a poll is created signal is generated and at that time Choice data is not populated in the database. I had the same issue and I solved it by adding delayed background task in celery for indexing the document.

Comment: How did you do that?

Comment: if you are not already aware of celery, You will require a good amount of time to set it up, it also requires a broker to carry messages. Follow this link for it https://realpython.com/asynchronous-tasks-with-django-and-celery/ 

for quick implementation, you can also use python threading to solve your problem just start a delayed thread , for refference -
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36314137/how-to-start-a-thread-in-python-after-waiting-for-a-specific-delay

Comment: Is there a specific amount of time I have to delay? Won't that depend on a lot of factors?

Comment: 1 second will be more than enough.